# Hint needed to Prove Limit of Cesaro Means

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am required to prove the following Proposition, but despite having spent considerable time thinking about it i have not been able to make much Headway.

**Could you please provide some hints and only hints to get me going.**

> **Proposition**. $$\text{ If }(x_n)\to x\text{ then }\left(\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}{n}\right)\to x$$

**PLEASE DO NOT PROVIDE COMPLETE SOLUTIONS**.

Comment: If you know Stolz-Cesaro, this is a walk in the park.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

For any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N>0$ such that for all $n>N$, we have $\;|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$ by hypothesis.

On the other hand, you have to check an  inequality of this kind:
$$\biggl|\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots +x_n}n-x\biggr|=\biggl|\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots +x_n-nx}n\biggr|<\varepsilon$$

Suppose  $n>N$ and split the last fraction as
\begin{align}
\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots +x_n-nx}n&=\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots +x_N-Nx}n+\frac{x_{N+1}+\dots +x_n-(n_N)x}n\\&=\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots +x_N-Nx}n+\frac{(x_{N+1}-x)+\dots +(x_n-x)}n.
\end{align}
Use the triangle inequality and choose an *ad hoc* value for  $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $x_n\to x$. Then for large $n$, most summands in $x_1+\ldots+x_n$ are close to $x$. The remaining (first) few summands are at a bounded distance from $x$. If we divide by $n$, the contribution of those first summands is controllably small, and apart from that, the average is close to $x$.